# Duplicated rows but also return the unique row which has duplicates

Tags: r, duplicates

I'm currently working on data sets that have a lot of duplicated rows.

I need to look into those rows and also the unique rows which kept out from the `duplicated()` function in R.

I'm now using 3 steps to achieve it:

```
dt1 <- dt %>%
filter(., duplicated(ID) == TRUE) %>%
mutate(., dup = 1)
dt <- left_join(dt, dt1, by = "ID")
```

then

`dt1 <- filter(dt, dup == 1)`

Since I need to repeat these steps very often.

So I wonder if there is a more simple way that gives the same outputs?

Comment: Can you add sample data to your question?

Comment: ... What I ask myself... Why would you want to 'look into' the deleted duplicated rows?